# Spring Boot 1.5.2 Controller Layer Testing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-test

I am trying to test my controller using the `@RunWith` & `@SpringBootTest`.

Controller

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String get(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

Test Class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class SampleTestNGApplicationTests{

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    public void testHome() throws Exception {

        ResponseEntity<String> entity = this.restTemplate.getForEntity("/home", String.class);

        assertThat(entity.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK);
        assertThat(entity.getBody()).isEqualTo("Hello World");
    }

}
```

Dependencies for testing

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Now `@RunWith` & `@SpringBootTest` annotation not found, Am I missing any library for it ? and I know there is so much changing in Spring Boot 1.5.2 is compare to Spring Boot 1.4.2.

## updates

Above question is resolved now, Actually I created new module for testing and controller is in differnt module. I am writing testing code under main->src->java of testing module, and I marked `spring-boot-starter-test` dependency scope to `test` in dependency, So removed `<scope>test</scope>`, and now I can get `@RunWith` & `@SpringBootTest` annotations.

now I am getting error `@ConditionalOnWebApplication (required) found 'session' scope (OnWebApplicationCondition)`

Error Log

```
=========================
AUTO-CONFIGURATION REPORT
=========================


Positive matches:
-----------------

   DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnWebApplication (required) found 'session' scope (OnWebApplicationCondition)

   DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DispatcherServletConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'javax.servlet.ServletRegistration'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)
      - Default DispatcherServlet did not find dispatcher servlet beans (DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DefaultDispatcherServletCondition)
```

Comment: jar corrupted, wrong import. Hard to tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of time spending on it, I added `webEnvironment` on `@SpringBootTest` and It is working for me.

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
```

will load the whole application context. I guess that is not necessary if you want to test only your controller layer. You can do something like this

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = HomeController.class)
public class HomeControllerTest {

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mvc;

  @MockBean
  private SomeService someservice // Mock any other dependencies which you have in your controller.  

  @Test
  public void someTest() throws Exception {

    doAnswer(invocation -> {
      // return some predefined data which would be returned from your service layer
    }).when(someservice).someMethod();

    mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/home").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(content().string("expectedString"));
  }

}
```

Comment: I removed SpringBootTest and added WebMvcTest, but its getting exception "Failed to load ApplicationContext"

Comment: remove @WebAppConfiguration and also don't use RestTemplate(this need whole application context to be setup) use Mockmvc as indicated in the example i gave